# Meta tag with condition tag in emails

Tags: email, woocommerce, html-email, meta-tags

I need to add the following meta tag to the WooCommerce email header.

```
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

This meta tag is to fix formatting issues in IOS email. But I cannot find a conditional tag to add the meta tag only if IOS.

Is the condition tag necessary here ? Does this have any effect on other email clients or will be neglected ?

Comment: That is not possible as you can't know on what device the email is going to be read…

Comment: So can I add this without condition tag ? Does this meta tag have any effects on other email clients ? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: I don't think that if you add this tag is going to affect other email clients, as this tag is only understandable by iOs, but it's just a speculation.

Comment: Ok. Is there an option to add meta tags to WooCommerce emails ? I cannot find any filter to do that. Also I believe emogrifier adds meta tag to the emails

Comment: No hooks for that, but you can override the template emails/email-header.php via your theme. Emogrifier just parse the CSS styles…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this meta tag without conditionals. Other email clients will ignore it.

The most comprehensive 'how to target' site, FWIW is here - but mostly this will have nothing to do with meta tags, because the targetting available is generally only for content in the `<body>`: https://howtotarget.email/

Comment: Thanks for the information. There are several meta tags available for different email clients . All those tags can be added without a conditional like those for outlook ?

Comment: Yep. I've never encountered any issues, but the only one people say you might need to add a conditional to (and using the only conditional element available for these tags) is for this: `<!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Have seen from profile that you have enough experience in email development. Do you have a blog or written tutorial for email development ?

Comment: There's a lot. You can pick up bits and pieces from the web, but unless you're working in it day to day, it's hard to get the nuances. So from that perspective, I would suggest learning from proper courses like those Jason Rodriguez of Litmus has done, https://thebetter.email/design/ (newer) or older one: www.modernhtmlemail.com --personally I've only written a couple of things about datatables, on medium, http://medium.com/@nathankeenmelb/

Comment: Ah, the freebies I have found on that site: https://thebetter.email/resources/